# Send a HTTP request in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a uri link that if I call it, it will send me a notification on my email address which is `http://localhost:8081/subscribe`. If I use it in my browser it  returns a JSON string : `{"subscriptionArn":"pending confirmation"}` and sends an email to email account and it works fine.

Now, I'd like to call this link and use it in my page web which made in AngularJS , I want to, when I click on the create button, call the link in the controller and send the notification on my email account.

I made a small code but it doesn't work , here is my code :

**service.js:**

```
var services = angular.module('ngdemoApp.services', ['ngResource']);
services.factory('Subscription', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8081/subscribe', {}, {
        subscribe: { method: 'GET' }
    });
});
```

**controller.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('ngdemoApp.controllers', []);
app.controller('CustomerListCtrl', ['$scope','GetCustomersFactory', '$location','Subscription',
           function ($scope, GetCustomersFactory, $location,Subscription) {

                // click-button to edit the customer
                $scope.editCustomer = function (customerId) {
                  $location.path('/customer-edit/' + customerId);   
                }

                // click-button to delete the customer
                $scope.deleteCustomer = function () {
                  //DeleteCustomerFactory.remove({ id: customerId });
                  $location.path('/customers');
                };

               // click-button to create a customer
               //here exactely where i'd to like call the link
               $scope.createNewCustomer = function () {
                   Subscription.subscribe();
                   $location.path('/customer-add');
               };

                   $scope.customers = GetCustomersFactory.query();
           }]);
```

Comment: Are any errors occuring?

Comment: there are no errors but I didn't get any mail on my email email address but when I directly  use the link in my browser , it works fine

Comment: Press F12 in firefox or chrome and view the network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code. You should redirect after the call has been complete by passing a callback function in the `subscribe` method

```
 $scope.createNewCustomer = function () {
       Subscription.subscribe(function(){
          $location.path('/customer-add');
       });
 };
```

Comment: it means that I will modify the method of service in service.js ?

Comment: @rochdibouslama no, the service in service.js is already coded in such a way that it will accept a callback.

Comment: @rochdibouslama you need to do it in controller itself..passing function in it will call on the resolve of subscribe method

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should use this code:

```
Subscription
  .subscribe().$promise
  .then(function () {
    $location.path('/customer-add');
});
```